# Silverstripe FulltextSearchable search with additional filter

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using FulltextSearchable to search content on my site but I would like to limit

```
$defaultColumns = array(
    'SiteTree' => '"Title","MenuTitle","Content","MetaTitle","MetaDescription","MetaKeywords"',
    'File' => '"Title","Filename","Content"'
);

foreach($searchableClasses as $class) {
    Config::inst()->update($class, 'create_table_options', array('MySQLDatabase' => 'ENGINE=MyISAM'));
    Object::add_extension($class, "FulltextSearchable('{$defaultColumns[$class]}')");
}
```

How can I limit this search to search 'File' table only for rows which have the 'Deleted' field set to '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
$files = DataObject::get("File","MATCH (Title,Filename,Content) AGAINST ('\"$query\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND Delete = 0");
```